# Log into Windows Server Ec2 instance using IAM user in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

This might be a rather simple question, but is it possible to log into an EC2 Windows Server instance over RDP, using an IAM user's credentials, or am I stuck using the password from the KeyPair?

Comment: @Paolo It was helpful thanks. We are in talks of changing our approach to this whole thing. I was in talks with AWS and they basically said there is no native support for how we are trying to get it to run (as least fingers touching things as possible). We were also throwing around the idea of using an on premisis AD with an AWS AD Connector, but that removes the cloud-native approach we are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that would be to have IAM identity center setup with SSM Fleet manager.
From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/fleet-rdp.html):

> Fleet Manager integrates with IAM Identity Center so you can connect to your instances without providing additional credentials.

Otherwise, you have to specify either username/password or a the .pem file:

> When connecting to your instance, you can use Windows credentials or the Amazon EC2 key pair (.pem file) associated with the instance for authentication.

Comment: Thanks. In addition to this is it possible to attach a role to the ec2 instance for whoever logs in? I know when attaching a role to an ec2 instance you can usually only do one. The main goal is to have different policies for whoever logs in.

Comment: @genesmith an ec2 instance can only have one instance role. You'd have to build a serverless solution to detach and attach an instance role based on the SSM Fleet manager session

Comment: @genesmith if you want to limit the permissions for different end users for the same server, you could consider creating a user for each of them with the required permissions, and then giving them the credentials for their specific user. They can then use the credentials inside the box (so an instance role on the instance isn't needed) to perform whatever action they need

Answer (score -1):

EC2 instance access over RDP steps as below:

1. In aws ec2 service site with your IAM login.
   [screenshot reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwHKF.jpg)
2. Select your windows server in EC2 instance list. let respective EC2 instance in running state. note then only "Connect" button will be active.
3. Select connect button. In the new window select 'RDP client' > select the 'Get Password'.
4. In 'Get password Window', import the pem which was associated with respective windows served in EC2 service. select 'Decrypt password'.
5. Copy the password, keep pasted in txt file for your future use.
6. Run 'mstsc' for remote desktop and type the public DNS address (which you can get it from above step 3 window) and login as .\Administrator and use the copied password for login.

Pre requisite steps to edited in EC2 windows instance:

1. Start the Windows Registry editor (type regedit in the "Start > Run" dialog)
2. Navigate to: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa] "LimitBlankPasswordUse"=dword:00000001 3. Change LimitBlankPasswordUse to 0 (zero) to enable the use of blank passwords, 1 to prevent blank passwords over the network.

this solution considered as alternate.

Comment: He's asking how to do it without password

Comment: @Gene Smith To change the default Windows behavior and allow login over the local network with blank password [https://www.speedguide.net/faq/how-to-connect-using-remote-desktop-without-a-password-435]().,steps from the link.
1. Start the Windows Registry editor (type regedit in the "Start > Run" dialog)
2. Navigate to: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]
"LimitBlankPasswordUse"=dword:00000001
3. Change LimitBlankPasswordUse to 0 (zero) to enable the use of blank passwords, 1 to prevent blank passwords over the network.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).